# Problems with Eclipse Oomph Installer at my company

Tags: eclipse, proxy, oomph

I am trying to get a Oomph setup script[1] at my company to work.
I downloaded the most current eclipse installer. I have set the proxy adress. On the Eclipse Importer dialog I selected the green plus, github projects, (i have cloned the repo before), I enter the location and select the project. The progress then stops at the "setup.p2:P2Task" (download depedencies) step with the following error:

```
ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director code=10053 Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found
```

At my company we are sitting behind an proxy and it signs every SSL connection with self-signed-certificate. Setup works fine on my machine at home.

[1] https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ConsistAnts/ConsistAnts/master/releng/de.hu_berlin.cchecker.releng/ConsistencyCheckingFramework.setup

Comment: they should learn to spell: ' one or mor required'!

Comment: @JonMarkPerry If you mean with _they_ Eclipse developer, you should learn how to contribute! (But in this case, it was [just a typo in the question](https://git.eclipse.org/c/equinox/rt.equinox.p2.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director/src/org/eclipse/equinox/internal/p2/director/messages.properties#n33).)

Comment: @howlger; any idea why some error messages from your link end with a full stop, other's don't?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Do you want to improve these messages (not all of these messages are error messages)?

Comment: @howlger; hey forget it, there's probably a very good reason for it. I was actually trying to determine how a copy/paste operation by the OP resulted in a typo.